# JaxRs @cosume to accept both JSON and URL param?

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs, resteasy

Just a quick question .. I have jaxrs GET method without any @consume annotation .. I can hit this over the browser and get results .. I want this method to consume JSON request at the same time I should be able to hit this over the browser .. I tried annotating @consume for both application Jason and urlencoded but couldn't get to support both at the same time .. Can some one shed a light with little piece of code pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Hit this over the browser" means `GET` request. Consume means `POST` request. These are two different types of RESTful methods and they can't be combines in one Java method. This is how you should do it:

```
@POST
@Consume(MediaType.APPLICAITON_JSON)
public void post(Foo foo) {
  // ...
}
@GET
public void get() {
  // ...
}
```

`get()` method will receive requests from your browser, when you "hit" it, while `post()` method will be the one that consumes JSON.